Android Emulator loses internet connection when connected to FortiClient VPN
Body:
I'm facing an issue where my Android emulator loses internet connection whenever I connect to my company's internal network using FortiClient VPN.
Details:

VPN Client: FortiClient VPN
Environment: Android Studio
Operating System: Windows 11
Emulator: Android Emulator

Steps to Reproduce:

Ensure you have a strong internet connection. Connect to the internal network using FortiClient VPN.
Open Android Studio.
Run the emulator using Cold Boot.
Notice the WiFi icon on the emulator; we have no internet connection, and even Google does not open.

Expected Results:
The Android emulator should maintain internet connectivity even when connected to the VPN.
Actual Results:
The emulator loses internet connectivity as soon as the VPN is connected.
Additional Information:
If anyone has experienced similar issues or has suggestions on resolving this, your help would be greatly appreciated.


The main problem is that the emulator is a virtual system on a virtual network. If your VPN profile disallows local network communication this also blocks emulator communication as the VPN can not distinguish between a virtual network and a physical network. Therefore all traffic is router through the VPN, even the traffic for the emulators (therefore the traffic will never reach your emulator). You have to talk to your VPN admins about this problem.
